# How to dynamically create a struct and use it as type parameter in a generic function

Tags: go, generics, reflection

Here is a working example to start with:

```golang
package main

type (
    builder    struct{}
    ISomething interface {
        DoSomething()
    }
    IMyStruct interface {
        MySomething()
    }
    myStruct struct {
        Num       int
        Something ISomething
    }
    Something struct{}
)

func AddSingleton[T any](b *builder, ctor any) {}

func (m *myStruct) MySomething()  {}
func (s *Something) DoSomething() {}

func main() {
    var something ISomething = &Something{}
    b := &builder{}
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        AddMyStruct(b, something, i)
    }

}
func AddMyStruct(b *builder, something ISomething, num int) {
    AddSingleton[*myStruct](b, func(something ISomething) *myStruct {
        return &myStruct{Num: num, Something: something}
    })
    AddSingleton[IMyStruct](b, func(obj *myStruct) IMyStruct {
        return obj
    })
}
```

The DI library I am using expects that the "obj" being passed in this snippet;

```golang
AddSingleton[IMyStruct](b, func(obj *myStruct) IMyStruct {
        return obj
    })
```

is a unique type.  It gets added to the DI in the first step and then when someone wants to get that same instance using IMyStruct it only resolves the last of that type added.
In my for loop, 2 get added and it always resolves the last one.
I can ask the container for an array of `[]IMyStruct`, which does give me 2 back, but they are the last `*myStruct` added.  i.e. the `objs[0].Num == 1`, `objs[1].Num == 1`.  It should be 0,1.

I can add uniqueness using generics;

```golang
type myStruct[T any] struct {
        Num       int
        Something ISomething
    }
```

but that doesn't work when I want to add these objects in a for loop.

I was thinking that if I dynamically create the type, being a perfect clone of the original myStruct, then everything that gets added to the di is a unique type.  Hence no problem resolving it "there can only be one".

I am hoping someone has reflection chops that I don't have to duplicate the `AddMyStruct`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question, but: The _type argument_ to a generic function MUST be known at compile time. Therefore it's simply NOT possible to use a dynamically created struct (using reflection) as the type argument of the generic function.

Answer (score 6):

> How to dynamical create a struct and then use it as a type paramater to a generic

You simply cannot do that.

(But I have to admit I do not understand your code.)

Comment: If there as an alternative to the generic AddSingleton func, where the type was passed in as the first argument we take the generic func out of the equation.  I think I did find some code where you could create a dynamic struct and then get the type.